# MySQL distinct and left, right

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have a table with day column like this:

```
2011-04-28, 2011-04-29 ...
day           count  name surname
2011-04-28    8       titi tutu
2011-04-28     12     tutu toto
2011-04-27     2      tutu toto
2011-03-12     10     tutu toto
```

I can obtain distinct day but not only month and year.

```
select distinct(day) from Table where day between "2011-03-01" and "2011-04-28";
```

I want only distinct month and year.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
select DISTINCT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `day`) as yearmonth
from Table
where day between '2011-03-01' and '2011-04-28';
```

Answer (score 1):

DISTINCT may be applied only to the whole row in mysql. So, you need to [extract](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) what you need first from the date.

```
select distinct(EXTRACT YEAR_MONTH FROM `day`) from Table 
      where day between "2011-03-01" and "2011-04-28";
```